# MATLAB num2str digits not displayed correctly in plot3

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I need to plot straight lines in-between points. Further I want to label those lines with numbers. It all works fine, but as soon as I have one-digit numbers AND two-digit numbers (e.g. `5` and `30`) the displayed number in the plot is only `3`.

How do I make MATLAB plot the full digit number?

My MATLAB code is:

```
numbers_string = num2str(numbers)
for i = 1 : number_of_lines
  plot3([x_start(i); x_end(i)],[y_start(i); y_end(i)],[z_start(i); z_end(i)], '-k');
  text((x_start(i)+x_end(i))/2, (y_start(i)+y_end(i))/2, (z_start(i)+z_end(i))/2, numbers_string(i))
end
```

The length of the `number_of_lines` and the `numbers_string` is the same, so my plot is working fine, just the labelling is causing problems.

I tried formatting but it did not work either.

Comment: Please create a [mcve], i.e. define all input variables (for example with random data).

Answer (score 2):

The `i`-th entry of a string will be a single character. For example, if

```
numbers = [42 99 1];
num_str = num2str(numbers);
```

then `num_str(1)`, `num_str(2)` and `num_str(3)` will be `'4'`, `'2'` and `' '`.

Instead of

```
number_str = num2str(numbers)
text(x,y,z,num2str(numbers_str(i)))
```

consider

```
text(x,y,z,num2str(numbers(i)))
```